# Which is the best (in time complexity) algorithm for finding a cycle in directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle

Also are there any randomized algorithms for that. I need to find a single cycle as fast as possible, not all cycles.

Answer (score 3):

> Which is the best (in time complexity) algorithm for finding a cycle in directed graph?

[Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%E2%80%99s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm). The time complexity if  O( | V | + | E | ).

Comment: Isn't that for all cycles? I need to find a single one as fast as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware that this is possible to do in the general case, but if you know certain properties of the graph (such as its "distance from cycle-freeness" as described in the paper below), there exist randomized algorithms that with high probability will find a cycle quickly.  Specifically, see the first algorithm in section 3 of the linked paper, with the corresponding analysis explaining how to extract the cycle.

As for deterministic algorithms, Mr. Saurav's answer is correct. In the worst case, you'll at least have to scan the entire input in order to correctly determine whether or not there is a cycle, which already requires O(|V| + |E|) time.

[1] http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4230

Answer (score 3):

the fastest one would be just a depth first graph traversal.
this is because you are not specifying any particular topology and so any other approach could face a bad worst case. Asymptotically O(|E|).
what you do is you label each node by the unique time you enter it as you recurse further and as soon as you find a node that already has a time label, there is your cycle and you halt.

Comment: a->b->c->....->z, aa->bb->cc->aa in the first one you don't have any cycle if you start from a or b or ... but in the second one you have it, There is no guarantee the graph is connected

Comment: if you've finished traversing a component, but you still have nodes to visit, you just continue your search from a node that hasn't been visited yet.

Comment: This is correct. In fact, according to my algorithms book: "A directed graph has a cycle if and only if its depth-first search reveals a back edge." A back edge being defined as guruslan said above.

Comment: So it's not O(|E|) it's O(|V|+|E|) , and @2-bits, think about a problems before matching it to your books

Comment: you can say so, but the |E| term is dominating |V|, so the complexity is still O(|E|).

Comment: @Saeed: Welp, it was the first solution that popped into my head, and my book happened to justify it. Is something wrong with that? I too would call it an O(|V| + |E|) problem though.

Comment: @guruslan: "the |E| term is dominating |V|". Not necessarily. Imagine a graph with |V|-3 disconnected vertices followed by a cycle of 3 vertices. The |V| term dominates because |E|=3 is a constant.